I accidentally brought in an exam slip with notes on it and was discovered by an invigilator
I sat for an exam at my university today and I had accidentally brought in an exam slip with notes on it. It was found by the invigilator and now I have an accused academic misconduct with a hearing to be conducted soon.
For your information, the exam slip is a piece of paper that contains information about our name, student number etc. along with other details about the exam we are sitting for. It is compulsory to bring in this paper and invigilators will check them along with our student card.
Now what happened was:
Last night before I went to bed, I wrote the notes to recap on what I had studied, and because it was just a recap I didn't bother to write it very clearly, I just scribbled a rough illustration of the architecture diagrams on it. It was not meant to be notes that I would read again later on nor was it meant for cheating, so I just grabbed the exam slip and wrote it on the empty spaces there. The paper had 2 sides, one with information another one blank. I purposely wrote on the side with words because I was confident I would check the paper before entering the exam hall should I forget to erase what I scribbled. I was afraid I would forget to erase it if I wrote on the blank side which I usually don't check.
However, I had pulled an all-nighter the day before to study for the exams and I was very tired, so after doing the last recap, I didn't erase it nor did I keep my notes, I just left everything on the desk and went to sleep. The next morning, I woke up late and was in a rush to get to school. I just left the other notes on the desk and grabbed the exam slip and threw it in my bag. Now because I live far from campus and I was already late, I arrived 30 minutes after the exam. So obviously, I was in a panic and just grabbed whatever was necessary and entered the exam hall. All I was thinking about was to write as fast as possible so that I could finish the exam on time. I had very much forgotten about the exam slip. So, while I was writing my name and student no. on every page of the answer script, the invigilator came to check my exam slip and saw the notes there. She showed me and my first reaction was to keep that back in my bag or erase it like I was planning to, cause it was really an honest mistake. Usually that would be possible if the exam hadn't started but because i was late, I missed the first few minutes where students were allowed to check and return any accidentally brought notes (I had discovered an accidentally left note in my pocket once before, but luckily that time, it was before the exam started so I managed to return the note.). So now, it became an academic misconduct (suspected of cheating) and I was told I will soon get an email to notify me of the hearing that I will need to attend.
I am very much panicked and worried right now, as I really didn't mean for this to happen. After checking the policies in the handbook, it says that the type of penalty include warning letter, fail grade for the course, or fail grade for the entire semester. It is my first time being accused of such, and I don't know what I should do. What makes me feel more devastated is the fact that this course is one that I must complete by this semester. I am transferring to another campus and this course is the last required course that I need to complete before I can transfer. If I fail and have to retake the course next semester, there would be complications in the application process and may cause me to not be able to transfer. I really had hope even at the moment the exam slip was discovered, cause I knew it wasn't on purpose and I didn't even open the slip at all nor did i manage to write anything on the answer script yet. I even thought I was lucky that the lecturer discovered it before I really started to do the exam, else nothing I say would have changed anything. But, I'm starting to think that the board will not believe I'm innocent even if I am.
I looked up other incidents online, and most people say that just be remorseful and admit that you cheated, and that the fail grade is what you deserve if you brought notes in. But do I really have to admit to something I didn't do? And I know it may be greedy of me, considering how I'm at risk of failing the entire semester, but I don't even want to fail this course. I studied like crazy for the past few days because the assignments took up most of my study week, and now some scribbles on the exam slip may cause my efforts to go down the drain. I also read about how some people had evidence to prove they didn't cheat, but the only evidence now is that exam slip which is proof of me bringing notes into the exam hall and no proof on my side to show that I didn't do it on purpose. To be honest, even if I wanted to cheat, I wouldn't do it so stupidly on the one piece of paper invigilators would definitely check. Or at least, I would have tried to hide it or something. At the time, I saw the invigilator coming to check my card and slip and I didn't even give it another thought, instead just went back to writing my student no. until the bomb dropped and it was too late.
It's really frustrating as it seems that all odds are against me, considering that 1. It was clearly stated that exam slips cannot be written on. (Sadly I didn't bother to read the many instructions) 2. There is evidence that notes were written and brought into exam hall 3. Even if it was a mistake, it is still considered my lack of responsibility to check beforehand.
I fully understand that it was all my fault for not taking the exam slip seriously, and just thinking of it as just another piece of paper. And I am very remorseful for not being more careful and responsible in checking the slip beforehand. However, do I really need to fail this course just because I wasn't careful? I get that the circumstances look suspicious, but what should I do or say during the hearing so that the board understands I really didn't plan to cheat? Is there anyone that can share their experience?
And please, what I need are some practical suggestions on what I should do during the hearing. Don't tell me to stick with it or just learn my lesson and move on. I have very much learned my lesson and will triple check my exam slip from now onwards. If it was another course, I wouldn't be so worried. But for this one, I really need to do everything possible to avoid failing because of this mistake.

Does this quesiton really need to be this long?

Honest mistakes tend to have simple explanations that lead directly to the error made and remorse for that error. Confabulated stories of innocence when caught tend to have a detailed explanations of how the many-step process that occurred was the only possible thing that could have happened at each step and things just miraculously all pieced together to lead to where you are now by no fault of your own. Which does yours sound like? You wrote on a paper you needed to bring to the exam because you planned to erase it? Maybe erasers have improved since I was a student but I don't buy it.

Since we are uninvolved, you maybe tell us the truth. However, if I were on the committee, I wouldn't be able to distinguish if you tell the truth or it's just an elaborate story you cooked up. I have seen too many cases of a big story, me finding a contradiction, then another story, then another contradiction, and so on, up to 3-4 such levels. The more you try to fudge the traces, the more suspicious things become. Own it, and understand that it is not distinguishable from a cheating attempt. And, to be honest, I do not fathom why anyone would write throwaway notes on an exam slip.

@BryanKrause This was my instinct too, but it sounds like the OP wrote their notes on a piece of paper that needed to be handed in or checked by someone in the process of verifying the student's identity. This sounds like an extremely nonsensical way to cheat. If I were the OP, I would focus on emphasizing the absurdity of trying to cheat in this way. The elaborate story about what happened, on the other hand, is strange and not terribly plausible (if it were not for the fact that this is a nonsensical way to cheat).

@AdamPřenosil Maybe the intent was to have notes in the exam room to look at until the last possible moment? Maybe they planned to "erase" but yet still be able to see the erased content and thought the invigilator wouldn't catch it? If they catch it then just hide it away, if they don't then use what's erased? I find that part of the story especially implausible, because it's not like erasing actually removes the content. It's sufficient to mask what's written before if you write over it, but I can't recall an eraser ever functioning well enough to completely hide what is written.

Did you omit some details?

@AdamPřenosil I have already written an account of the incident on the day itself for the incident report. At that time, I was completely out of it and I just wrote like 2 sentences of what happened. Something like " I came in late and invigilator found exam slip with notes on it." That was all. The invigilator asked me in private, and I just told her "I have no idea". But, later on, I tried to recall what had happened and how it all begin cause I assumed they would ask questions about all details, which is why I wrote it all out so you guys could get the whole picture. Is it too elaborate?

@CaptainEmacs Yes, I do feel that it was ridiculous of me to write things on that paper at the very first place. I would have found it hard to understand if it wasn't that I myself did such a thing. But then again, sometimes we do stupid things without giving it a second thought. Well, I guess I didn't think of the slip as anything but just another piece of paper until yesterday.

@Aruralreader So far, this is as detailed as it can get. Is there something specific that you want to know more about?

Thank you to everyone for their opinions. I posted this ques yesterday not long after the incident happened and when I was very desperate to resolve this misunderstanding. But after reading all your comments and reflecting on myself, I decided that I should just own up to it. There is nothing I can do to prove that it wasn't intentional, rather, there is proof that notes were brought in.

So, the only thing I can prove is that I didn't need to cheat. During the hearing, I will just give a simple account of what happened and accept the fail for this course. Regardless of the intention, it is true that there is a very big chance of cheating. I could have not touched that piece of paper throughout the exam, but the moment I did open it, it is already considered cheating. So, it is best I fail and retake the exam or the course (whichever given by the committee), and earn the grade without any chance of cheating, to be fair to everyone.

@user59237 I guess owning up is the best thing one can do in your specific situation. You say you can prove to them you didn't need to cheat. What is your proof?

There is no magical "avoid all consequences of your actions" phrase. All you can do is be honest. The committee may believe you or they may not.
However, it will probably work in your favor that this is the first time you did something like this.
Other than that there is not much we can tell you; we are not on that committee.
